# SQL query with count() from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I got the following tables:

```
pictures
------------------------------------
id
name
views

votes
------------------------------------
id
user_id
pic_id
```

I want to get a result from a query that will give me each picture id, with the views of the picture, and the total votes from the table `votes` for the specific pic_id

example:

pictures.id, pictures.views, total votes

1 ------------ 78------------------ 123

2 ------------ 23------------------- 69

and so on...

The code I tried:

```
SELECT `pictures`.`id`,`pictures`.`views`, COUNT(`votes`.`pic_id`) as votes
FROM `pictures` 
JOIN `votes`
ON `pictures`.`id` = `votes`.`pic_id`
```

But it doesn't give me the reuslt I desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `GROUP BY` clause.

The use of `LEFT JOIN` will display all records on table `pictures` with or without matching record on table `votes`.

```
SELECT  a.id, a.name, a.views,
        COUNT(b.pic_id) TotalVotes
FROM    pictures a
        LEFT JOIN votes b
            ON a.id = b.pic_id
GROUP   BY a.id, a.name, a.views
```

Comment: thanks! well explained, defenitely solved a problem issue with that LEFT JOIN since I haven't thought about the situation when no one has voted to some picture

Answer (score 1):

Use left join with a group function ,normal join keyword means an inner join and you  need a left join for one to many relation

```
SELECT `pictures`.`id`,`pictures`.`views`, COUNT(`votes`.`pic_id`) as votes
FROM `pictures` 
LEFT JOIN `votes`
ON `pictures`.`id` = `votes`.`pic_id`
GROUP BY `pictures`.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT `pictures`.`id`,`pictures`.`views`, COUNT(`votes`.`pic_id`) as votes
FROM `pictures` 
JOIN `votes`
ON `pictures`.`id` = `votes`.`pic_id`
GROUP BY `votes`.`pic_id`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to try like this using the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT `pictures`.`id`,`pictures`.`views`, COUNT(`votes`.`pic_id`) as votes
FROM `pictures` 
JOIN `votes`
ON `pictures`.`id` = `votes`.`pic_id`
group by `pictures`.`id`
```